# Wordpress child theme functions.php not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Below is my child theme functions.php :

```html
<?php

function remove_image_zoom_support() {
    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
}
add_action( 'wp', 'remove_image_zoom_support', 100 );

/*PROBLEM CODE BELOW*/
 
///////////////////////////////
// 1. ADD FIELDS
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'bbloomer_add_name_woo_account_registration' );
 
function bbloomer_add_name_woo_account_registration() {
    ?>

  <p class="form-row form-row-first">
    <label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
  </p>

  <p class="form-row form-row-last">
    <label for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
  </p>

  <div class="clear"></div>

  <?php
}
 
///////////////////////////////
// 2. VALIDATE FIELDS
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', 'bbloomer_validate_name_fields', 10, 3 );
 
function bbloomer_validate_name_fields( $errors, $username, $email ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'billing_first_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: First name is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'billing_last_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Last name is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    return $errors;
}
 
///////////////////////////////
// 3. SAVE FIELDS
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'bbloomer_save_name_fields' );


function bbloomer_save_name_fields( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );
    }
}
 ?>
```

I tried to see if the child theme is working, so I added background color to style.css. It didn't work, but function remove_image_zoom_support works.

I am trying to customize 'My Account Register Form' in WooCommerce, so I referred to this site: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-first-last-name-account-register-form/. For some reason, the register form looks just the same as before (The form only has e-mail field and password field as default).

Is there any class or something I should correct? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: try adding `!important` at the end of your css style, for instance `background-color: red !important;`